# OrientDB: How to traverse a graph and get the full path of a given type

Tags: graph, traversal, orientdb

I have a programming language graph in which packages are structured as Eclipse represents, so every package is a vertex. I want to, starting from a class, traverse the edge belongsTo where the vertex's class is code_Package. In the end, I want to print the full package name. Is that possible?

The structure is similar to this one:
[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understood correctly, your situation is something like this:

```
create class code_Package extends V
create property code_Package.name string

create class code_ClassUnit extends V
create property code_ClassUnit.name string

create class belongsTo extends E


# class sdc.spd.ssi.Main
create vertex code_Package set name = 'sdc'      #12:0
create vertex code_Package set name = 'spd'      #12:1
create vertex code_Package set name = 'ssi'      #12:2

create vertex code_ClassUnit set name = 'Main'   #13:0


create edge belongsTo from #13:0 to #12:2
create edge belongsTo from #12:2 to #12:1
create edge belongsTo from #12:1 to #12:0
```

[image]

What you're asking can be achieved by defining a function (e.g. **join**):

```
var result = "";
for(var i = input.length - 1; i >= 0; i--){
  result += input[i] + ".";
}

return result.substring(0, result.length - 1);
```

like this:

[image]

and then:

```
select join($all.fullPath[0])
let $all = (select unionall(name) as fullPath from (traverse out('belongsTo') from #13:0))
```

output:

[image]